# Save Document to Database C# and DocX.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, server, docx

I want to know that how can I save this document in Database. Document is successfully loaded and manipulated. But on Button click, I want it to be inserted in Database. How to save Memorystream to database?

```
protected void genDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{

DocX document = DocX.Load(@"g:\\OfferDocuments\\MainDocument.docx");
document.ReplaceText("Name", "Ayesha", false, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

con.Open();

sqltrans = con.BeginTransaction();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [tbl_Offers]([PropFile]) VALUES (@PropFi)", con, sqltrans);        


cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PropFi", file);        
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.Parameters.Clear();

sqltrans.Commit();

con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: You have cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PropFi", file); Where is `file` declared?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to specify a memorystream blob in an SQL statement. You can create an empty row, set the values and update/commit it.

http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=279&t=How_to_save_and_retrieve_PDF_documents_to_and_from_a_database_using_CSharp